# ColdFusion PDF to text using cfpdf - Formatting issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfpdf

We have a requirement to extract the content of an uploaded PDF and then show it in a text area with the same formatting. Our application runs on ColdFusion 10.

We used `cfpdf` however the extracted text is a single paragraph with No formatting.

Is there anyway in ColdFusion to read the PDF as text retaining the source formatting (100% accuracy is not expected) .

Note:

1. We tried itext and it works very well however it comes with a licensing cost which I don't want to spend as I'm only going to use this single feature from the bundle that itext is providing.
2. Tried PDFbox but the formatting is not retained.